# Cannot start WDS service

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, wds

I built this WDS server that I made into a RODC also. After running the dcpromo, it get this error message that the WDS service is not started and could not start.

I found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistadeployment/thread/d0056f63-eb60-4f47-a515-a40c1a342341/) so I tried changing the logon account to my domain admin account.

Now it gives me an error when I try to start the service saying:

> "Windows could not start the Windows
>   Deployment Services Server service on
>   SERVER. Error 1297: A privilege that
>   the service requires to function
>   properly does not exist in the service
>   account configuration..."

Do I have to adjust some security settings somewhere for my domain account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ran DCPROMO you effectively got rid of the "local security policy".  You now need to assign the right through the "Domain Controller Security Policy".