# starting wds error 1297

Tags: windows-server-2008, wds

I am installing WDS as part of an MCITP course. standalone WDS acting as Domain controller and DHCP/DNS.

WDS is conigured but I cannot start the service, I am getting error 1297.

I have tried

- Setting Log on as account to my Domain Administrator account/Another
- Super User account Set my Remote Install folder for Everyone access
- Checked IP and DNS were set up correct
- WDS has been configured

I see from another thread I need to add assign the right through Domain Controller Security Policy? How do I do this? I cannot see the option in gpmc.msc

Comment: Dupe? http://serverfault.com/questions/203595/cannot-start-wds-service

Comment: Yep seen that one but it didn't help as I am not sure how to apply the fix - don't want to dig up an old thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the NETWORK SERVICE account is not granted the appropriate user rights.

Look into [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946399) on MS, if the server is not a DC, use Method 1 or Method 2. If the server is a domain controller, use Method 3 or Method 4.

Don't get confused that article is about Terminal Services, instructions there apply to any service (any service that is configured to start by using the NETWORK SERVICE account may experience similar symptoms).

Comment: It worked! Outstanding. Thank you for that you are a life saver.

Comment: Good to hear that!